# Outputting the data from several sql tables without having a common value

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a select query which combined several tables. `PRODUCTION_ORDER_RESULTS`, `PRODUCTION_ORDERS` and `SERVICE_GUARANTY_NEW` have common value however `STOCKS` table does not.

```
SELECT PR_ORDERS.ARRIVED_CITY,
       PR_ORDERS.MONTAJ_DATE,
       PR_ORDER_RESULT.TRANSFER_DATE,
       PR_ORDERS.P_ORDER_ID,
       PR_ORDER_RESULT.P_ORDER_ID,
       SG.SALE_CONSUMER_ID,
       SG.IS_SERI_SONU,
       S.BRAND_ID,
       S.PROPERTY
  FROM workcube_test_1.PRODUCTION_ORDER_RESULTS PR_ORDER_RESULT,
       workcube_test_1.PRODUCTION_ORDERS        PR_ORDERS,
       workcube_test_1.SERVICE_GUARANTY_NEW     SG,
       workcube_test_1.STOCKS                   S
 WHERE PR_ORDER_RESULT.P_ORDER_ID = PR_ORDERS.P_ORDER_ID
   AND PR_ORDER_RESULT.PR_ORDER_ID = SG.PROCESS_ID
```

when I run the query, it shows the output as below.

[image]

The problem here is there are four data rows returned from `PRODUCTION_ORDER_RESULTS`, `PRODUCTION_ORDERS`, `SERVICE_GUARANTY_NEW` and once I have added the `STOCKS` table, `arrived_city`, `montaj_date`, `transfer_date` columns are side by side with `STOCKS` table's rows, but the columns value should be null, not filled with data.

The way I tried is UNION of `STOCKS` table, however unioned table values are ignored, can not use them in html blocks.

[image]

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I'd prefer using joins however it is coded by someone else. I m just allowed to make this kind of changes.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English Speaking Community, @chatay, please stick to making posts and comments in English. There are other SO communities for other languages, if English is not your strong point.

Answer (score 0):

there needs to be at least one more join condition among tables where there's for `STOCKS` table, I think there might exist such a column `STOCK_ID` within a table such as `PRODUCTION_ORDER_RESULTS` in order to join with `STOCKS` table. I think this should be the reason for multiple returning rows. If there's no common column, then the returning data will be produced as many as the number of records within `STOCK` table due to existing `CROSS JOIN` logic within the current query. So rearrange your query as

```
SELECT PR_ORDERS.ARRIVED_CITY,
       PR_ORDERS.MONTAJ_DATE,
       PR_ORDER_RESULT.TRANSFER_DATE,
       PR_ORDERS.P_ORDER_ID,
       PR_ORDER_RESULT.P_ORDER_ID,
       SG.SALE_CONSUMER_ID,
       SG.IS_SERI_SONU,
       S.BRAND_ID,
       S.PROPERTY
  FROM workcube_test_1.PRODUCTION_ORDER_RESULTS PR_ORDER_RESULT
  JOIN workcube_test_1.PRODUCTION_ORDERS        PR_ORDERS
    ON PR_ORDER_RESULT.P_ORDER_ID = PR_ORDERS.P_ORDER_ID
  JOIN workcube_test_1.SERVICE_GUARANTY_NEW     SG
    ON PR_ORDER_RESULT.PR_ORDER_ID = SG.PROCESS_ID
  JOIN workcube_test_1.STOCKS S
    ON PR_ORDER_RESULT.STOCK_ID = S.ID
```